# Drupal Custom Entity Page not found

Tags: drupal, entity

I am actualy trying to implement my first own entity using this tutorial:

http://www.istos.it/en/blog/drupal-entities/drupal-entities-part-3-programming-hello-drupal-entity

So far anything worked fine, but now i ran in some problem I couldnt get fixed.
After creating my new entity, I get redirected to the page "slider/(id)". But it says that the page could not be found. When I try to open the URL manualy I get the same error.

Here is my code:
he_slider.module

```
/**
    * Implements hook_entitiy_info()
    */

function he_slider_entity_info(){
    $slider_info['slider'] = array(
        'label' => t('Slider Item'),
        'controller class' => 'SliderController',
        'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
        'base table' => 'slider',
        'uri callback' => 'he_slider_uri',
        'fieldable' => TRUE,
        'entity keys' => array(
            'id' => 'sid',
        ),
        'static cache' => TRUE,
        'bundles' => array(
            'slider'=> array(
                'label' => 'Slider',
                'admin' => array(
                    'path' => 'admin/structure/slider/manage',
                    'access arguments' => array('administer slider'),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'view modes' => array(
            'full' => array(
                'label' => t('Full Slider Item'),
                'custom settings' =>  FALSE,
            ),
        )
    );

    return $slider_info;
}

/**
    * URI Callback function
    */

function he_slider_uri($slider){
    return array(
        'path' => 'slider/' . $slider->id,
    );
}

/**
    *  Load the a single or multiple entities
    */

function he_slider_load($sid = NULL, $reset = FALSE){
    $sids = (isset ($sid) ? array($sid) : array());
    $slider = slider_load_multiple($sids, $reset);
    return $slider? reset ($slider) : FALSE;
}

function he_slider_load_multiple($sids = array(), $conditions = array(), $reset = FALSE){
    return entity_load('slider', $sids, $conditions, $reset);
}


/**
    * Provides the Pages to administer and view the entities
    */

function he_slider_menu(){
    $items['admin/content/slider/add'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add Slider Item',
        'page callback' => 'he_slider_add',
        'access arguments' => array('create slideritem'),
    );
    $items['admin/structure/slider/manage'] = array(
        'title' => 'Slider Administration',
        'description' => 'Manage Slider Structure',
        'page callback' => 'he_slider_info',
        'access arguments' => array('administer slideritem'),
    );
    $items['slider/%slider'] = array(
        'title callback' => 'he_slider_page_title',
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'he_slider_page_view',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access arguments' => array('view slideritem'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    $items['slider/%slider/edit'] = array(
        'title' => 'Slider Edit',
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'he_slider_page_edit',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
         'access arguments' => array('edit slideritem'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    $items['admin/content/slider/add'] = array(
        'title' => 'Add Slider Item!',
        'page callback' => 'he_slider_add',
        'access arguments' => array('create slideritem'),
    );
    return $items;
}

function he_slider_permission(){
        return array(
        'administer slideritem' =>  array(
            'title' => t('Administer Slider'),
            'restrict access' => TRUE,
        ),
        'view slideritem' => array(
            'title' => t('View Slideritems'),
        ),
        'edit slideritem' => array(
            'title' => t('Edit Slideritems'),
        )
    );
}


function he_slider_info() {
    return ('Welcome to the administration page for your Slideritems!');
}

function he_slider_page_title($slider){
    return $slider->sid;
}

function he_slider_page_view($slider, $view_mode = 'full'){
    $slider->content = array();

    // Build fields content.
    field_attach_prepare_view('slider', array($slider->sid => $slider), $view_mode);
    entity_prepare_view('slider', array($slider->sid => $slider));
    $slider->content += field_attach_view('slider', $slider, $view_mode);

    return $slider->content;
}


function he_slider_field_extra_fields() {
    $return = array();
    $return['slider']['slider'] = array(
        'form' => array(
            'title' => array(
                'label' => t('Title'),
                'description' => t('Slider Title'),
            ),
        ),
    );


    return $return;
}

/**
    * Implements the slider add form, where we are able to create our new entities
    */

function he_slider_add() {
    $slider = (object) array (
        'sid' => '',
        'type' => 'slider',
        'title' => '',
    );

    return drupal_get_form('he_slider_add_form', $slider);
}


function he_slider_add_form($form, &$form_state, $slider) {
    $form['title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Note'),
        '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Save'),
    );

    field_attach_form('slider', $slider, $form, $form_state);

    return $form;
}

/**
    * Implements the Entitiy Edit form
    */

function he_slider_page_edit($slider) {
    return drupal_get_form('he_slider_add_form', $slider);
}

/**
    * Validates the Entity Add form
    */

function he_slider_add_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    $slider_submission = (object) $form_state['values'];
    field_attach_form_validate('slider', $slider_submission, $form, $form_state);
}

function he_slider_add_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $slider_submission = (object) $form_state['values'];
    field_attach_submit('slider', $slider_submission, $form, $form_state);
    $slider = he_slider_save($slider_submission);
    $form_state['redirect'] = "slider/$slider->sid";
}

function he_slider_save(&$slider) {
    return entity_get_controller('slider')->save($slider);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function he_slider_views_api() {
    return array(
        'api' => 3,
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'slider') . '/views',
    );
}

/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function he_slider_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id=='_slider_add_form'){
        $form['submit']['#weight'] = 99;
    }
}
```

he_slider.controller.inc:

```
class SliderController extends DrupalDefaultEntityController {
    public function save($slider) {
        drupal_write_record('slider', $slider);
        field_attach_insert('slider', $slider);
        module_invoke_all('entity_insert', $slider, 'slider');
        return $slider;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$items['slider/%slider'] = array(
```

Drupal's menu system will look for a function named `slider_load()`, whereas your entity load function is named `he_slider_load()`. This causes the router to bail out and throw a 404.

To fix it, simply change that line to

```
$items['slider/%he_slider'] = array(
```

And clear your caches.

Comment: I quoted you on drupal.stackexchange.com:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100446/custom-entitiy-page-not-found/100536#100536
Hope that is ok for you ?! :-)